# multiple statments in inline c# on and asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline-code

I have the following line in my aspx file:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# MediaHelper.GetMediaUrl(Container.DataItem) %>' Height="114" Width="152"/>
```

Is it possible to add another line to the inline c# something like this?

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# MediaHelper.GetMediaUrl(Container.DataItem); SetImageSize(this) %>' Height="114" Width="152"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple method calls to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
<asp:Image 
    ID="Image1" 
    runat="server" 
    ImageUrl='<%# MediaHelper.GetMediaUrl(Container.DataItem) %>' 
    Height="<%# MediaHelper.GetMediaHeight(Container.DataItem) %>" 
    Width="<%# MediaHelper.GetMediaWidth(Container.DataItem) %>"
/>
```

Or just bind an object to the control that has all of those values exposed as properties.

Comment: what would the return type have to be? string?

Comment: In the example above, the return type for `GetMediaUrl` would be string. The return type for `GetMediaHeight` and `GetMediaWidth` would be `int` (or possibly `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit`).

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that this is not possible. But you could write another method on this helper class which will invoke the two operations at once.

```
<asp:Image 
    ID="Image1" 
    runat="server" 
    ImageUrl='<%# MediaHelper.GetMediaUrlAndSetImageSize(Container.DataItem, this) %>' 
    Height="114" 
    Width="152"
/>
```

Also mixing C# code with ASPX might lead to spaghetti. I would tend to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: cool thanks! yeah this code is really messy.  It was written that way by the previous developer and we dont have time to go through and fix it so I just have to get what i have working...  How can i pass the image to the method. I just noticed passing "this" is the wrong object..

Comment: @MBU, which image? Is it part of the current data bound item? `Container.DataItem` might be sufficient as argument in this case.

Comment: i think so. basically i want to method to return the imageurl and at the same time i want to dynamically set the height and width of the image. Is that possible?

Comment: @MBU, you could also use the DataBinding syntax `<%# %>` to set the `Width` and `Height` properties.